# how to avoid word breaking while line wrapping in python (CLI)

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface

I am writing a script in python that reads text from file and print random part of this file to the screen. The problem I have is that sometimes the line is too long and words are split in the middle. How can I force python to split words at words?

Comment: Does it really matter if you're just printing to the console?

Comment: The top google hit for `python wordwrap` is the `textwrap` module in the standard library. Pretty sure it does exactly what you want.

Comment: or just use split() then join() back together within line length constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python script is unaware of the width of the output string.
You can add a parameter width= to the commandline options of your script, but that shouldn't be what you want.
When you call your script, redirect the output to `fold`. Fold has options for witdth and cut add word boundaries:

```
$ python yotam.py 2>&1 | fold -s -w80
```